# Why i got null from this query

Tags: mysql

Following is my sql query kindly let me know why is it returning null

```
Select STR_TO_DATE ('11-APR-74','%e%b%Y')
OR
Select DATE_FORMAT ('11-APR-74','%e%b%Y')
```

Comment: what do you want to do? convert from string to date?

Comment: What's your query about, Malik?

Comment: well i am comparing between two dates so i thought by getting dates in %d%m%y the compare will gonna give accurate result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL STR_TO_DATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

> The server scans str attempting to match format to it. ... Scanning
>   starts at the beginning of str and fails if format is found not to
>   match.

This is why your first query fails: 11-APR-74 does not look like %e%b%Y, so date cannot be parsed. You should do instead

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE ('11-APR-74','%e-%b-%Y')
```

From [MySQL Date and Time types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html):

> Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date
>   parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example,
>   '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or day-month-year
>   orders commonly used elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98').

This is why your second query fails: 74 is not a valid day of month, you should do instead

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT ('74-APR-11','%e%b%Y')
```

Note, that DATE_FORMAT is usually used on DB values, not string literals as you do - to get an output different from the default one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert from string to date

```
Select STR_TO_DATE ('11-APR-74','%d-%b-%y')
```

Comment: how can i get this string in `%d%b%y` ?

Comment: what exactly do yu want to do?

Comment: well i am comparing between two dates so i thought by getting dates in `%d%m%y` the compare will gonna give accurate result

Comment: can you add sample data and desired result?

Comment: data is like in this format `11-APR-74` and i have to compare less than and greater than on these dates.. getting dates in `%d%m%y` always gives accurate result for comparing in terms of less than and greater than will it be the same in the case of `STR_TO_DATE ('11-APR-74','%d-%b-%y') <  STR_TO_DATE ('11-APR-78','%d-%b-%y')` for all possible inputs of dates?

Answer (score 0):

use it like ::

```
Select STR_TO_DATE ('11-APR-74','%e-%b-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `'%e%b%Y'` format does not correspond to `'11-APR-74'` string value (as `STR_TO_DATE` function expects), and because `'11-APR-74'` value is of type `CHAR`, but not `DATETIME` (as `DATE_FORMAT` function expects).

If you want to reformat a date represented by a `CHAR` value, convert it from its original format to `DATETIME` first, and then convert it to a string of desired format:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('11-APR-74','%e-%b-%Y'),'%e%b%Y');
```

By the way, you could strip dashes with a plain string sunction:

```
SELECT REPLACE('11-APR-74','-','');
```